# ScalaTest and java.util.Iterable

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is there a way to implicitly convert `java.util.Iterable<T>` to something that will typecheck in a matcher like `foo.items should have size(10)` ? I've tried importing `scala.collection.JavaConversions` but still got a compiler error. Currently I explicitly convert it with `scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScala`. Scala version is 2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `Iterable` isn't supported out of the box. Anything which extends at least `java.util.Collection` (i.e. `java.util.List`) should do though. There is an implicit conversion defined in trait `ShouldWrappers`:

```
implicit def convertToJavaCollectionShouldWrapper[T](o: Collection[T]): 
             JavaCollectionShouldWrapper[T]
```

To see which types are supported out of the box with `ShouldWrappers` have a look at the [corresponding page of the ScalaDocs](http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5b/#org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers).

You can of course implement your own.